# jquery sound not playing

Tags: jquery, audio, position

I want a sound to play when a div has an x position value of more than 50. I control the div with my arrow keys.

http://jsfiddle.net/vvccvvcc/f9fsnLcu/3/

I'm guessing `audioElement.play()`   isn't working.

Neither the sound nor the alert pop up (function playSound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed code below
http://jsfiddle.net/f9fsnLcu/4/

```
First your sound handle was out of scope, so i defined it in window:
 window.audioElement = audioElement = blabla
Second you were trying to compare object with a number. Don't need to wrap x.left in jquery. 
if (x.left>50)
```